# NameError in Account#show, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nameerror

I have been unable to find a solution to this problem. It is similar to a lot of the questions asked before, but I believe something is different in mine. I am currently getting this error:

```
NameError in Account#show
uninitialized constant Account::AccountProces
```

It is throwing the error in my view:

```
<%@account.account_process.each do |process|%>
    Name: <%=process.name%><br/>
<%end%>
```

Now I have checked names and everything matches up except AccountProces should be AccountProcess. I don't know why it is showing that AccountProces only has one s. I have searched my entire directory for something that only has 1 s. I have yet to find anything.
Here is my model:

```
class AccountProcess < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :account_id, :name
    validates :account_id, presence: true
    validates :name, presence: true

    belongs_to :account
    def as_json options={}
    {
       id: id,
       name: name,
       open_count: open_count,
       created_at: created_at,
       update_at: updated_at

    }
    end
end
```

Here is my migration:

```
class CreateAccountProcesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :account_processes do |t|
         t.references :account

         t.string :name, :null => false, :default => ""

         t.timestamps
      end
   end
end
```

Here is my simplified account Model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :computer_id, :allotted_time, :domain, :tracking, :used_time, :username, :account_process_attributes

   validates :username, :presence => true
   validates :computer_id, :presence => true

   has_many :account_process, :dependent => :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_process

   def as_json options={}
   {
     id: id,
     computer_id: computer_id,
     domain: domain,
     username: username,
     tracking: tracking,

     account_process_attributes: account_process,

     created_at: created_at,
     update_at: updated_at
   }
   end
end
```

That should be everything that I can think of that would cause this issue. I have other attributes that are with account such as history and Program. They are almost identical to account process and they don't throw any errors. It throws this error both in my views and when I am trying to save to the db using my REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :account_process, :dependent => :destroy
...
end
```

to

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :account_processes, :dependent => :destroy
...
end
```

and change this association in your view too.

The association name in `has_many`should always be pluralized, ActiveRecord will determine the class by singularizing the association-name.

If it fails to correctly generate the class name, you could do something like this:

```
has_many :account_processes, :class_name => "AccountProcess"
```

Comment: That gives me this error:
No association found for name `account_process'. Has it been defined yet?

Comment: You should rename your calls to this association too (like here `@account.account_process.each`)

Comment: Alright, I will have to get it to work with plurals, but working with it a bit I was able to get it to work by adding <code>:class_name => "AccountProcess"</code> to my association. It was giving me a <code>undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass</code> error.